# Select multiple max values after GROUP BY query

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

Suppose I have a table look like this:

```
   date ID  income
0   9/1 C   10.40
1   9/3 A   33.90
2   9/3 B   29.10
3   9/4 C   19.30
4   9/4 B   17.80
5   9/5 B   9.55
6   9/5 C   11.10
7   9/5 A   13.10
8   9/7 A   29.10
9   9/7 B   29.10
```

I want to find out the ID who made the most income for each date. The most intuitive approach would be writing

`SELECT ID, MAX(income) FROM table GROUP BY date`

But there are two IDs who made the same *MAX income* on `9/7`, I want to retain all ties on the same date, by using that query I will ignore one ID on `9/7`, and `29.1` appears on `9/3` and `9/7`, any other approach?

Comment: your dbms name please

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin SQLite3 package in python 3

Comment: Please show us the expected output.  Do you want to _retain_ all ties for max income a given date, or do you always want only _one_ record per date?  If the latter, then what is the logic you want to use for breaking a tie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A join based approach doesn't have this problem, and would retain all records tied for the max income on a given date.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT date, MAX(income) AS max_income
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY date
) t2
    ON t1.date = t2.date AND t1.income = t2.max_income
ORDER BY
    t1.date;
```

The way the above query works is to join the complete original table to a subquery which finds, for each date, the maximum income value.  This has the effect of filtering off any record which did not have the max income on a given date.  Pay close attention to the join condition, which has two components, the date, and the income.

If your database supports analytic function, we can also use `RANK` here:

```
SELECT date, ID, income
FROM
(
    SELECT t.*, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY income DESC) rnk
    FROM yourTable t
) t
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: 8   9/7 A   29.10
9   9/7 B   29.10 what will return for this?

Comment: I can't read your comment.  Reformat so that each record is surrounded in separate backticks, e.g. `8 9/7 A` ...

Comment: just check the op's description last 2 lines

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin Um...if I read correctly, the OP _wants_ to retain all ties for the max on a given date.  A join based approach does this.

Comment: but at the same time he want to ignore one if matches 2

Comment: I don't understand his English to be conveying this, and English is my first language.  I will ask the OP for clarification.

Comment: This is very nice solution, as it retains all ties on the same date. Could you tell me a little bit more about how does it work? The t1* and t2 part is a little bit confusing....

Comment: @user3697665 I added a description of what the query is doing.  In SQLite, you're basically forced to use this (well...there is another way, using a correlated subquery, but it might not perform as well as what I wrote).  In most other databases, you could use the second version I gave.

Answer (score 0):

Try below using subquery and as you've tie for one date so take minimum ID which'll give you one id from date 9/7

```
select date,min(ID),income
from
(SELECT t1.date, t1.ID,t1.income
FROM tablename t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT date, MAX(income) AS mincome
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY date
) t2 ON t1.date = t2.date AND t1.income = t2.mincome
)X group by date,income
```

Answer (score 0):

one approach can be like below

```
 with cte1
     (
    Select t1.*
    FROM yourTable t1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT date, MAX(income) AS max_income
        FROM yourTable
        GROUP BY date
    ) t2
        ON t1.date = t2.date AND t1.income = t2.max_income

     ) select min(ID) as ID, date,income from cte1 
      group by date,income
```

As you not mentioned which id you need in case of two ID's(when income is same on a particular date) so i took minimum id among them when two id's income is same on a particular date But at the same time you may use max() function also

Comment: What I find almost hilarious is that a few minutes ago you were peppering my answer with comments telling me that I understood wrongly, and then you went off and gave a very similar answer :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you got me wrong read ops last 2 line he describe that he want to consider only one id incase of two ids income same on a particular date which was not covered in simple sub-query join and i mentioned this on my answer